# Dropwizard integration testing with Testcontainers

Tags: dropwizard, testcontainers

I'm trying to run dropwizard's integration tests against a dockered database.

- [Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.1.2/docs/)
- [Testcontainers](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java)

What I've tried:

```
@ClassRule
public static final PostgreSQLContainer postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer();

@ClassRule
    public final DropwizardAppRule<Configuration> RULE = new DropwizardAppRule<>(
            Application.class,
            CONFIG_PATH,
            ConfigOverride.config("dataSourceFactory.url", postgres.getJdbcUrl()),
            ConfigOverride.config("dataSourceFactory.user", postgres.getUsername()),
            ConfigOverride.config("dataSourceFactory.password", postgres.getPassword())
    );
```

I get `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mapped port can only be obtained after the container is started`

Chaining these together does not work either

```
@ClassRule
    public static TestRule chain = RuleChain.outerRule(postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer())
            .around(RULE = new DropwizardAppRule<>(
                    Application.class,
                    CONFIG_PATH,
                    ConfigOverride.config("dataSourceFactory.url", postgres.getJdbcUrl()),
                    ConfigOverride.config("dataSourceFactory.user", postgres.getUsername()),
                    ConfigOverride.config("dataSourceFactory.password", postgres.getPassword())
            ));
```

Finally this works, but as I understand it runs the new DropwizardAppRule for every test and this is **not good**...

```
@ClassRule
public static final PostgreSQLContainer postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer();

@Rule
    public final DropwizardAppRule<Configuration> RULE = new DropwizardAppRule<>(
            Application.class,
            CONFIG_PATH,
            ConfigOverride.config("dataSourceFactory.url", postgres.getJdbcUrl()),
            ConfigOverride.config("dataSourceFactory.user", postgres.getUsername()),
            ConfigOverride.config("dataSourceFactory.password", postgres.getPassword())
    );
```

So how can I chain the rules such that PostgreSQLContainer is initiated first and container has started before creating the DropwizardAppRule?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got it working by initiating PostgreSQLContainer as singleton.

```
    public static final PostgreSQLContainer postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer();
    static {
        postgres.start();
    }

    @ClassRule
    public final DropwizardAppRule<Configuration> RULE = new DropwizardAppRule<>(
            Application.class,
            CONFIG_PATH,
            ConfigOverride.config("dataSourceFactory.url", postgres.getJdbcUrl()),
            ConfigOverride.config("dataSourceFactory.user", postgres.getUsername()),
            ConfigOverride.config("dataSourceFactory.password", postgres.getPassword())
    );
```